# Java no name static method

Tags: java, static-methods

What is this?

```
public class ABC {
   public ABC() {
         System.out.println("world");
   }
   static {
         System.out.println("hello");
   }
}
```

Will print:
hello
world

I don't really understand this, or what kind of method that static code is.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's called a "static initialisation block".

It runs when the class is first loaded; only once.

For example, a constructor will run each time the class is instantiated; the static block only runs once, when it's first loaded statically by the VM/Class loader.

Comment: See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) for the JLS description of static initializers and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) for a JLS description of the order of initialisation, which can be important.

Answer (score 12):

I think it's worth noting the static block will be run exactly once each time a classloader loads a class. This means if you have more than one classloader, the block can execute more than once.