# Singletons as Synthetic classes in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am reading Programming in Scala, and I don't understand the following sentence (pdf p.112):

> Each singleton object is implemented as an instance of a *synthetic class* referenced from a 
>   static variable, so they have the same initialization semantics as Java statics.

Does this mean the if I have a singleton **FooBar** in scala, the compiler will create a class named **FooBar$**?

Also what does the author mean by "referenced from a static variable"? Is there a hidden static variable somewhere holding a reference to some **FooBar$** class?

I appreciate any help here.

Comment: Yes, I think you understand it.

Comment: :-( I don't I just kind of guessed!

Comment: The trick is that the static variable references the instance, not the class.  In other words, the Scala object `FooBar` is reference in Java as `FooBar$.MODULE$`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The chapter 31 of the same "Programming in Scala" is more precise:

> Java has no exact equivalent to a singleton object, but it does have static methods.
>
> The Scala translation of singleton objects uses a combination of static and instance methods. **For every Scala singleton object, the compiler will create a Java class for the object with a dollar sign added to the end**.
>   For a singleton object named `App`, the compiler produces a Java class named `App$`.
>   This class has all the methods and fields of the Scala singleton object.
>   The Java class also has a single static field named **`MODULE$`** to hold the one
>   instance of the class that is created at run time.
>   As a full example, suppose you compile the following singleton object:

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

> Scala will generate a Java App$ class with the following fields and methods:

```
$ javap App$
public final class App$ extends java.lang.Object
    implements scala.ScalaObject{
  public static final App$ MODULE$;
  public static {};
  public App$();
  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
  public int $tag();
}
```

> That’s the translation for the general case.

Comment: Thanks that makes it clear. I guess I should've just skipped forward in the book :-)

Comment: What's the purpose of `public static {};`?

Comment: @ChristopherPerry `static {}` is a **static initialization block**, to initialize the singleton. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/1836232/6309 or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 10):

You're basically correct.

If you have the singleton

```
object Singleton {
  def method = "Method result"
}
```

then compilation gives you

```
Singleton.class
Singleton$.class
```

and for the bytecode you find, first for `Singleton`:

```
public final class Singleton extends java.lang.Object{
public static final java.lang.String method();
  Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #11; //Field Singleton$.MODULE$:LSingleton$;
   3:   invokevirtual   #13; //Method Singleton$.method:()Ljava/lang/String;
   6:   areturn
}
```

that is, a public static method for each method of the class that references something called `Singleton$.MODULE$`, and in `Singleton$`:

```
public final class Singleton$ extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
public static final Singleton$ MODULE$;
  Signature: LSingleton$;

public static {};
  Signature: ()V
  Code:
   0:   new #9; //class Singleton$
   3:   invokespecial   #12; //Method "<init>":()V
   6:   return


public java.lang.String method();
  Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
  Code:
   0:   ldc #16; //String Method result
   2:   areturn


private Singleton$();
  Signature: ()V
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #20; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   putstatic   #22; //Field MODULE$:LSingleton$;
   8:   return
}
```

Where you see that `MODULE$` is what holds the instance of `Singleton$`, and `method` is just an ordinary method.

So, that's all there really is to it: create `Singleton$` with a static field called `MODULE$` to hold the unique instance of itself, populate that field, and then create a `Singleton` with static methods that forward all static calls to the appropriate methods from `Singleton$`.

Comment: Thanks, that is kind of clear, but what are the numbers 0 1 4 and so on? Sorry I am not intimately familiar with bytecode lol :(

Comment: On the left, they're bytecode addresses.  Line numbers, essentially.  On the right, they refer to tables of classes, methods, fields, or whatever else is appropriate.