# Scala object MODULE$

Tags: scala

What's the purpose of Scala object **MODULE$**?

The following Scala object:

```
object TestScalaObject {
 val TEST_SYMBOL = "*"
 def testMethod(x : String) : String = x
}
```

compiles into two bytecode files **TestScalaObject.class** and **TestScalaObject$.class** which if I disassemble to get the equivalent Java code I get:

*TestScalaObject.class*:

```
public final class TestScalaObject extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final java.lang.String testMethod(java.lang.String);
    public static final java.lang.String TEST_SYMBOL();
}
```

*TestScalaObject$.class*:

```
public final class TestScalaObject$ extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
    public static final TestScalaObject$ MODULE$;
    public static {};
    public java.lang.String TEST_SYMBOL();
    public java.lang.String testMethod(java.lang.String);
}
```

I can see a `public` `static` `final` TestScalaObject$.MODULE$ but what is it used for if I can access everything I need through **TestScalaObject.TEST_SYMBOL** and **TestScalaObject.testMethod()** if I ever wanted to do that from Java

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721046/singletons-as-synthetic-classes-in-scala for some related info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MODULE$` holds an instance of the instantiated class.  See the Singleton pattern in Java.  I don't know of a good source for it, so here's the Wikipedia entry for [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).