# Why can't I assign an Scala Object to a Java variable?

Tags: java, scala, object

I have this monolithic Java-Application that I want to port to newer techniques and I want to apply Scala wherever it makes sense.

Now I translated a rather huge java-singleton class implementation to a Scala object.

In another class I used to do this (JAVA):

```
   public class MyOtherClass 
   {
        protected MyClass myClass;

        public MyOtherClass()
        {
            myClass = MyClass.getInstance();
        }
   }
```

Now I'd like to do the following:

```
   public class MyOtherClass 
   {
        protected MySCALAClass myClass;

        public MyOtherClass()
        {
            myClass = MySCALAClass$.MODULE$;
        }
   }
```

But this doesn't work. It says:

> Required MyScalaClass, Found MyScalaClass$

I also tried to create a small function

```
def getInstance() = this
```

but of course this yields the same problem.

Any ideas? I have searched this topic and I see how it is not a problem if you just want to call the methods of the object, but I would need to rewrite many, many calls to the "myClass"-object to even test this.

**edit**: I'm fully aware that I could rename every call to "myClass" to "MySCALAClass", but that is no real fix, just a workaround and it is tedious for a big project.

Comment: You may need to declare your `myClass` variable as `protected MySCALAClass$ myClass;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @neuronaut 's comment is correct.

See following questions:

- [Scala object MODULE$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934738/scala-object-module)
- [Singletons as Synthetic classes in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721046/singletons-as-synthetic-classes-in-scala)

The singleton class (`MySCALAClass$` in your case) is not a subclass of the original class (`MySCALAClass`) and so the singleton object (`MySCALAClass$.MODULE$`) is not an instance of it either.