# How Spark tasks in the same executor share variables (NumberFormatException with SimpleDateFormat)?

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, simpledateformat, rdd

The spark docs says that

> By default, when Spark runs a function in parallel as a set of tasks on different nodes, it ships a copy of each variable used in the function to each task.

If I create a Java `SimpleDateFormat` and use it in RDD operations, I got a exception `NumberFormatException: multiple points`.

I know `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe. But as said by spark docs, this `SimpleDateFormat` object is copied to each task, so there should not be multiple threads accessing this object.

I speculate that all task in one executor shares the same `SimpleDateFormate` object, am I right?

---

This program prints the same object `java.text.SimpleDateFormat@f82ede60`

```
object NormalVariable {

  // create dateFormat here doesn't change
  // val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd")

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd")

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Test").setMaster("local[*]")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)

    val dates = Array[String]("1999.09.09", "2000.09.09", "2001.09.09", "2002.09.09", "2003.09.09")

    println(dateFormat)

    val resultes = spark.parallelize(dates).map { i =>
      println(dateFormat)
      dateFormat.parse(i)
    }.collect()

    println(resultes.mkString(" "))
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code to the question ?

Comment: I added my code, could you check my code, thanks.

Comment: I ran your code in Spark shell without exceptions. Where do you get an exception, exactly?

Comment: @pzecevic it's a 'heisenbug' a concurrent change to the non-thread safe `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: I presume that this has to do with how Spark serializes the closures, the [ClosureCleaner](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/ClosureCleaner.scala)  and singleton Scala objects in the JVM, but exactly what's going on goes beyond me. Probably @joshrosen could provide an authoritative answer

Comment: In the meantime, I think you want to create an instance of `SimpleDateFormat` within the closure to solve this problem. `SimpleDateFormat` uses a mutable `Calendar` instance inside. It's 'mutable state' in disguise.

Comment: Thanks for the response @maasg. We did fix the problem using that way. I'm just curious about Spark's behaivor, which is not consistent with its document.

Comment: I found this question+response to be quite helpful in understanding what's going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369916/what-is-the-right-way-to-have-a-static-object-on-all-workers

Answer (score 1):

As you know, `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe.

If Spark is using a single core per executor (`--executor-cores 1`) then everything should work fine. But as soon as you configure more than one core per executor, your code is now running multi-threaded,  the `SimpleDateFormat` is shared by multiple Spark tasks concurrently, and is likely to corrupt the data and throw various exceptions.

To fix this, you can use one of the same approaches as for non-Spark code, namely `ThreadLocal`, which ensures you get one copy of the `SimpleDateFormat` per thread.

In Java, this looks like:

```java
public class DateFormatTest {

  private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> df = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>(){
    @Override
    protected DateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    }
  };

  public Date convert(String source) throws ParseException{
    Date d = df.get().parse(source);
    return d;
  }
}
```

and the equivalent code in Scala works just the same - shown here as a `spark-shell` session:

```scala
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

object SafeFormat extends ThreadLocal[SimpleDateFormat] {
  override def initialValue = {
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmmss")
  }
}

sc.parallelize(Seq("20180319 162058")).map(SafeFormat.get.parse(_)).collect

    res6: Array[java.util.Date] = Array(Mon Mar 19 16:20:58 GMT 2018)
```

So you would define the `ThreadLocal` at the top level of your job `class` or `object`, then call `df.get` to obtain the `SimpleDateFormat` within your RDD operations.

See:

- http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/dateformat-with-multiple-threads.html
- ["Java DateFormat is not threadsafe" what does this leads to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to)