# Spark broadcast a value that is known at compilation time

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running a Spark job and I have an object Constants that contains all constant values I am using in my program.

As an example let us assume that we have the following object:

```
 object Constants{
   ...
   val aSet=Set[String]("foo","bar","etc",...}
   ...
 }
```

Is it worth broadcasting the `aSet` val to the nodes, or is it already available to them since  it is part of the code and it it is known in compilation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that every worker will have access to the object. Some related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369916/what-is-the-right-way-to-have-a-static-object-on-all-workers).