# Scala : Significance of file generated with $ during compile

Tags: scala

Please note that I am beginner to Scala. Can someone please explain what is the significance of the class file with $ in it.

-rw-r--r--  1 rodiee  staff  130 Aug  9 10:39 HelloWorld.scala

-rw-r--r--  1 rodiee  staff  586 Aug  9 10:40 HelloWorld.class

-rw-r--r--  1 rodiee  staff  635 Aug  9 10:40 **HelloWorld$.class**

Thanks
-Scala Beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files ending with `$` are jvm static classes related to the "singleton" `object`s in your `.scala` files

You can read this other answer for reference: [Singletons as Synthetic classes in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721046/singletons-as-synthetic-classes-in-scala)

Comment: Thank you Gurghet!