# Using reflection to verify all instances of a trait have a unique field

Tags: java, scala, reflection, reflections

Consider the following code. Animals should have a unique ID. I want to dynamically verify (in a test) that all concrete subtypes of Animal have unique IDs. I want my test to fail if, for example, Cat and Fish both try to pass in `uniqueId` = 2.

```
sealed trait Animal {
  val uniqueId: Int
}

abstract class Mammal(val uniqueId: Int) extends Animal

abstract class Fish(val uniqueId: Int) extends Animal


case class Dog(age: Int, name: String) extends Mammal(1)

case class Cat(favouriteFood: String) extends Mammal(2)

case class Salmon(isCute: Boolean) extends Fish(3)
```

I'm using [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to get the classes.

```
    import org.reflections.Reflections
    val reflections                 = new Reflections("package.blah")
    val allSubtypes: Seq[Class[_ <: Animal]] = reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Animal]).asScala.toList
    val concreteSubtypes: Seq[Class[_ <: Animal]] = allSubtypes.filter(c => !Modifier.isAbstract(c.getModifiers))
```

I'm starting to suspect it might not be possible but would love to be wrong! I have the classes but no way to instantiate instances of them because all the constructors differ and I'm not sure if I can access the `uniqueId` from just the class.

Comment: Perhaps every instance could register its `uniqueId` field in a `Set` somewhere when it is constructed.

Comment: I think you can't do what you are trying to do, because you don't have an instance, and this value us instantiated only when an instance is created.

Comment: If you saw my original answer, I've added an approach which works without changing code structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tomer Shetah's comment says, this doesn't seem to be possible as stated. But it may work if you can split `Animal` and `AnimalCompanion`, and make the id actually unique per `AnimalCompanion`:

```
abstract class AnimalCompanion(val uniqueId: Int)

sealed trait Animal {
  def companion: AnimalCompanion
  def uniqueId = companion.uniqueId
}

abstract class Mammal(val companion: AnimalCompanion) extends Animal

abstract class Fish(val companion: AnimalCompanion) extends Animal

case class Dog(age: Int, name: String) extends Mammal(Dog)

object Dog extends AnimalCompanion(1)

case class Cat(favouriteFood: String) extends Mammal(Cat)

object Cat extends AnimalCompanion(2)

case class Salmon(isCute: Boolean) extends Fish(Salmon)

object Salmon extends AnimalCompanion(3)
```

Then you find all subtypes of `AnimalCompanion` in the same way, and because they are all `object`s they'll [have the `MODULE$` field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721046/singletons-as-synthetic-classes-in-scala) holding the instance and that instance will have the `uniqueId` field and getter method.

Without testing, something like this should work:

```
val allCompanionClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[AnimalCompanion]).asScala
val allCompanionInstances = allCompanionClasses.map(_.getField("MODULE$").get(null))
val allUniqueIds = allCompanionInstances.map(x => x.getClass().getMethod("uniqueId").invoke(x))
```

and then it remains to check they are actually unique e.g. by

```
allUniqueIds.toSet.size == allUniqueIds.size
```

---

Without changing the structure, I'd consider a different approach: provide the instances yourself, just verify they include all classes.

```
val instances = Set(Dog(0, ""), Cat(""), Salmon(true))

// allSubtypes defined in the question
assert(allSubtypes.toSet == instances.map(_.getClass))
// same logic as above but we already have a Set
assert(instances.map(_.uniqueId).size == instances.size)
```